# Solving a differential system

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, numerical-analysis-of-pde

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb R$ with Lebesgue density, i.e. $\mu(dx)=\mu(x)dx$. We aime to find increasing and decreasing functions $\phi_{+}: \mathbb R_+\to \mathbb R_{+}$ and $\phi_{-}: \mathbb R_+\to \mathbb R_{-}$ s.t. $\phi_{\pm}(0)=0$ and

$$\phi_{\pm}'(x)~~=~~\frac{1~-~F_{\mu}\big(\phi_+(x)\big)~+~F_{\mu}\big(\phi_-(x)\big)}{2\phi_{\pm}(x)\mu\big(\phi_{\pm}(x)\big)} \mbox{ for all } x>0,$$

where $F_{\mu}$ denotes the cumulative distribution function of $\mu$. My question is how to specify $(\phi_+,\phi_-)$ in terms of $\mu$? If there is some numerical shcema, I'm equally glad to know about it.

I find a solution if $\mu$ is symmetric, i.e. $\mu(x)=\mu(-x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. Then it is easy to guess that $\phi_{\pm}=\pm\phi$ with

$$\phi^{-1}(x)~~=~~\int_0^x\frac{y\mu(y)}{1~-~F_{\mu}(y)}dy \mbox{ for all } x\in\mathbb R_+.$$

If someone knows how to treat the general case, please let me know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The unknown functions in your ODE appear to be $\phi_{\pm}$. So I'm a bit confused by your question: *how to specify the density $\mu$*.  In fact, it appears that $\mu$ is known or given or already specified.

Comment: I have reformulated my question. Here we assume that $\mu$ is regular enough.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Yes. Do you have some idea?

Comment: Is the support of $\mu$ over all reals?  Please specify all of your assumptions on $\mu$.  Once we establish existence/uniqueness of a solution then we can approximate these ODEs.  But I don't see that the right hand side is regular enough without more assumptions on $\mu$.

Comment: Generally, $\mu$ is supported on the whole real line. And in order to solve the system, the density $x\mapsto \mu(x)$ is assumed to be smooth.

Comment: Are the tails of $\mu$ heavier or lighter than Gaussian?

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Yes. The aim is to solve the system, so we may add any suitable assumption right now.

Answer (score 4):

For simplicity, let's assume initially  that the support of $\mu$ is the whole real line, so that $F$ is a homeomorphism $ \mathbb{R} \to (0,1) $. Let's denote $b:=F(0)=\mu(-\infty,0]=1-\mu[0,+\infty)\in(0,1)$.

The relevant function is the strictly convex function $\Phi :(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$\Phi(t):=\int_{b}^t F^{-1}(s)\, ds  $$
which is the Legendre transformation of $\int_0^x F(t)dt$. It has minimum value at $t=b$, and $\Phi(t)\to+\infty$, both for $t\to0$ and  $t\to1$ (indeed 
$\Phi(0)=\int_{b}^0 F^{-1}(s)\, ds=\int_ {-\infty}^0  F(t) dt$: writing them in terms of the density function $\mu(s)$ as double integrals, and using Tonelli's theorem, one finds that both integrals diverge).

Let's denote $\Psi_{+}:=(\Phi_{|[b,1)})^{-1}: \mathbb{R}_+ \to[b,1)$ and $\Psi_-:=(\Phi_{|(0,b]})^{-1}:\mathbb{R}_+\to(0,b]$ . Note that $\Psi(t):=1-\Psi_+(t)+\Psi_-(t)=\big|\{\Phi\ge t\}\big|$ is the inverse function of the monotone decreasing rearrangement of $\Psi$.

Consider the solution $u:[0,+\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ of the first order autonomous ODE

$$u'(t) = \frac{1}{2} \Psi (u ),\quad t\ge0$$
with $u(0)=0$, given  explicitly by
$$u^{-1}(x)=2\int_0^x\frac{dy}{ \Psi (y) }.$$

This integral is finite for all $x\ge0$ and diverges for $x\to+\infty$, so $u$ is a homeo $\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}_+$ .

Then it is easy to check that $\phi_{\pm}:=F^{-1}\circ\Psi_\pm\circ u $ are defined  $\mathbb{R}_+$, diverges to $\pm\infty$ for $x\to+\infty$, and solve the initial problem written as
$$ 2\phi_+ F'(\phi_+)\phi_+'=2\phi_- F'(\phi_-)\phi_-'=1-F(\phi_+)+F(\phi_-)$$
that we can write equivalently, because $\phi_\pm=F^{-1}\circ F\circ \phi_\pm=\Phi'\circ F\circ \phi_\pm$, in the form
$$ 2(\Phi\circ F\circ \phi_+)'=2(\Phi\circ F\circ \phi_-)'=1-\Psi_+\circ\Phi\circ F\circ \phi_+  +\Psi_-\circ\Phi\circ F\circ \phi_- .$$

Conversely, if $\phi_\pm$ solve the initial system, the latter equation shows that $\Phi\circ F\circ \phi_+=\Phi\circ F\circ \phi_-$ because they coincide at $0$ and have the same derivative, and in fact solve the above equation for $u$.

$$*$$

**Rmk.** The assumption on the support of $\mu$ is not crucial; if it is not the whole real line, $F$ is constant on some open set, and $F^{-1}$ has jumps and it is only defined as a left inverse of $F$; the integral for $\Phi$ is however well defined.

Comment: Why is $\mu(-\infty,0] = \mu[0,+\infty)$?

Comment: sorry, it was a typo, thank you, fixed.

Comment: That's an interesting transformation.

Comment: @ Pietro Majer Very nice solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ Pietro Majer Could you please specify a bit more about the definition of $\Psi$, i.e. ``$\Psi(t):=1-\Psi_+(t)+\Psi_-(t)=|\{\Psi\ge t\}|$ is the inverse function of the monotone decreasing rearrangement of $\Psi$''. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, I mean $\Psi(t)=|\{\Phi\ge t\}|$ (fixed).  The m.d.r. of $\Phi$ is a decreasing function  on $(0,1)$  whose super-level sets have the same measure of the corresponding super-level sets of $\Phi$.
Since the function $\Phi$ is convex on $(0,1)$ and the sub-level set $\{\Phi< t\}$ is  the interval $(\Psi_-(t),\Psi_+(t) )$ its  complement has length $\Psi(t)=|\{\Phi\ge t\}|$.

Comment: To be precise, it seems to me that the solutions $\phi_\pm$ have domains $[0,\tau_\pm)$, and $\phi_\pm(t)\to\pm\infty$ for $t\to\tau_\pm$,  
where respectively $\tau_-=2\int_0^{\Phi(0)} \frac{dy}{\Psi(y)}$ and $\tau_+=2\int_0^{\Phi(1)} \frac{dy}{\Psi(y)}$. This implies that at least one among $\tau_-$ and $\tau_+$ is infinite,  and both are infinite if and only if $\Phi(0)=\Phi(1)$.

Comment: @ Pietro Majer Thanks again for the reply. In your answer, should it be $\|\Phi\|_{\infty}=\max\{-\Phi(0), \Phi(1)\}$ and $\Psi_-:=(-\Phi_{|(0,b]})^{-1}: [0,-\Phi(0))\to (0,b]$? As $\Phi(0)$ is negative.

Comment: Actually no, $\Phi(0)$ is positive (the integrand is negative but $\int_b^0=-\int_0^b$). $\Phi$ is convex (the derivative is  $\Phi'(t) = F^{-1}(t)$, increasing). Note also that $|\Phi'(t)|\to\infty$ for $t\to0$ and $t\to1$, which implies $\Psi_\pm'(x)\to0$ resp. for $x\to\Phi(0)$ and  for $x\to\Phi(1)$.

Comment: But in fact i think $\Phi(0)=\Phi(1)=+\infty$, which simplify things. Just write $\Phi(0)$ $\Phi(1)$ in terms of the density $\mu(x)$ as a double integral, and use Fubini.

Comment: @ Pietro Majer $\Phi(0)=\int_b^0F^{-1}(s)ds<0$ as $F^{-1}$ is positive, where $F^{-1}$ denotes the inverse of $F$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46622/discussion-between-pietro-majer-and-codegolf).

Comment: I edited and modified, taking into accounts the fact that $\Phi(t)$ goes to $+\infty$ at $0$ and $1$, which semplifies the discussion.